# saving files to scaleway storage php methode

Tags: php, laravel, cloud-storage

how to upload an image to [scaleway](https://scaleway.com) storage by laravel or PHP methods?

Comment: Updated my answer. It was much easier than I thought :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel uses [FlySystem](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem) under the hood to abstract file storage. It provides several drivers out of the box including: S3, Rackspace, FTP etc.

If you want to support Scaleway, you would need to write a Custom Driver, which you can read more about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#custom-filesystems).

Edit: It seems from the [documentation of Scaleway](https://www.scaleway.com/docs/object-storage-feature/), it supports AWS CLI clients, which means, this should be quite easy to add support for in FlySytem. I tried the following and it worked.

I added a new driver in `config/filesystems.php` as follows:

```
'scaleway' => [
    'driver' => 's3',
    'key' => '####',
    'secret' => '#####',
    'region' => 'nl-ams',
    'bucket' => 'test-bucket-name',
    'endpoint' => 'https://s3.nl-ams.scw.cloud',
]
```

and then, to use the disk, I did the following:

```
\Storage::disk('scaleway')->put('file.txt', 'Contents');
```

My file was uploaded.

EDIT: I also made a [PR](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem/pull/993) to get Scaleway accepted in the list of adapters for League's FlySystem. It got merged. You can see it live [here](https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/docs/adapter/scaleway-object-storage/).

Comment: Cool. If it matters, I made a PR to add Scaleway to the list of supported adapters on League's FlySystem: https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem/pull/993